How to assert two union type variables has the same type
Copyable example code:
export type Node<
  NodeData extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>,
  NodeType extends string = string
> = {
  id: string;
  data: NodeData;
  type: NodeType;
};

export type SourceNode = Node<
  {
    current: string;
  },
  "source"
>;

export type TargetNode = Node<
  {
    targetType: number;
  },
  "target"
>;

export function isRuleNode(node: FlowNode): node is RuleNode {
  return node.type === "rule";
}

export type RuleNode = Node<
  {
    ruleName: string;
  },
  "rule"
>;

export type FilterNode = Node<
  {
    name: string;
  },
  "filter"
>;

export type FlowNode =
  | RuleNode
  | FilterNode
  | SourceNode
  | TargetNode

function updateNodeData(nodes: FlowNode[], data: Partial<FlowNode["data"]>) {
  // if the union type is the same?
  nodes = nodes.map((node) => { // problem is here
    return {
      ...node,
      data: {
        ...node.data,
        ...data,
      },
    };
  });

  return nodes;
}

// RuleNode here can be changed
let data: Partial<RuleNode["data"]> = {
  ruleName: "test",
};

let nodes: FlowNode[] = [];  // type here cannot be changed

updateNodeData(nodes, data);

Basically, I want to update the data on different types of nodes. The type of data is known but not always the same type. The type of node is the union type FlowNode.
I want to assert in the map function if the type of node is the same as the data.
This works but I don't want to assert on every possible node type.
nodes = nodes.map((node) => {
  if (isRuleNode(node)) {
    return {
      ...node,
      data: {
        ...node.data,
        ...data,
      }
    }
  }

  return node
})


please provide MVC in the typescript playground

Please [edit] to make your code a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now there are undeclared/unimported/private types and values that give us a wall of errors you're not asking about. Please either define everything in the example code, or even better, replace externally-defined stuff with built-in versions (that is, try to make the example minimal and not just reproducible). Note that the code should be here as plaintext. A link to a web IDE would be a nice supplement but it doesn't suffice by itself to be a [mre].

• See prev comment; that link doesn't suffice to be a [mre]. We need all the code here as plaintext. I can [edit] that in for you if you want. • Does this question depend on zustand/react/xyflow etc? If so then you should mention that in the question (and tag the question if there are tags). If not then you should edit the code to remove those dependencies so we can focus on the TypeScript issue.

@jcalz I have removed xyflow. I think it does not depends on react or zustand but I cannot reproduce the problem without zustand using my understanding of typescript. You are more than welcome to help me edit it of course.

Okay I've edited the plaintext example in and tagged with zustand. I don't know anything about zustand so I'm not sure I can work on this much, but if I figure it out I'll let you know.

(see prev comment) Maaaaybe this approach, using ms/TS#47109, but again, not sure what the zustand stuff is doing so who knows. Let me know how you want to proceed.

@jcalz Your code works. zustand is removed. Please have a check. I am still trying to figure out what is going on here. Any other approach to solve this issue? I will accept this as a solution if nothing else. Thanks for your help.

Now that I look at this I'm very confused why you're just unconditionally adding the data to every node. How do you know that the nodes are the right type? I can mess with types so that it compiles, like this playground link shows, but that just works because excess properties don't break types. Is this really your goal?

@jcalz You're right. So the real question is how to make sure data  has the same type as node.data so excess properties won't be given to the wrong node. let nodes: FlowNode[] = []; is better not to change because it is set somewhere else.

Hmm, so does that mean you should [edit] the question to explain what you're doing and that you need some sort of... runtime check? Maybe? I upvoted the answer below because it seems that you need something like areSameNodes().

If you change the data parameter to include type, then it becomes much easier, as you can check it for equality.
type PartialNode<N extends Node> = N extends Node<infer Data, infer Type> ? { type:Type; data: Partial<Data> } : never;

function areSameNodes<N extends FlowNode>(lhs: FlowNode, rhs: PartialNode<N>): lhs is N {
  return lhs.type === rhs.type;
}

function updateNodeData<N extends FlowNode>(nodes: FlowNode[], data: PartialNode<N>): FlowNode[] {
  // if the union type is the same?
  return nodes.map((node) => {
    return areSameNodes(node, data) ? {
      ...node,
      data: {
        ...node.data,
        ...data.data,
      },
    } satisfies FlowNode : node;
  });
}


It works. Can you give some explainations? I have read about Conditional Types. Why satisfies  is needed here? Why can't I write updateNodeData(nodes: FlowNode[], data: PartialNode<FlowNode>)?

@Evilolipop satisfies isn't actually needed here, I just left it in because it verifies that the inferred type is what we want. You need N to be specific otherwise areSameNodes(node, data) doesn't change the inference of node.data.
